# How to avoid making a fetch() request every time you do something like sort, filter, etc. some JSON data in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When the page loads it brings data to the page good:

```
fetch("theData.json")
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (objArray) {
    mainFunctionThatPresentsTheData(objArray);
  });
```

But then I have multiple buttons that do sorting, for example lowest to highest price, highest to lowest based on some attribute of the json objects in the JSON Array, etc.

I managed to successfully perform this functionality, however, I don't think it's really efficient because I make a new fetch() request every time I click a "sort" button:

```
function customSort(sortOrder, byWhatAttribute) {
  output.innerHTML = "";
  fetch("theData.json")
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (objArray) {
      for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        objArray[i].somethingInTheJsonObjArrayThatIWantToSort.sort(sortOrder(byWhatAttribute));   
      }
      mainFunctionThatPresentsTheData(objArray);
    });
}
```

I tried this:

```
let globalEmptyArray; //<----- addition 1
//this gets called when the page loads or gets refreshed
fetch("theData.json")
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (objArray) {
  globalEmptyArray = objArray; //<----- addition 2
    mainFunctionThatPresentsTheData(objArray);
  });

function customSort(sortOrder, byWhatAttribute) {
  output.innerHTML = "";
  // addition 3 ... the globalEmptyArray is not supposed to be empty anymore.
  for (let i = 0; i < globalEmptyArray.length; i++) {
    globalEmptyArray[i].somethingInTheJsonObjArrayThatIWantToSort.sort(sortOrder(byWhatAttribute));
    
  }

  mainFunctionThatPresentsTheData(globalEmptyArray);
}
```

The customSort() function gets called like this:

```
sortBySomethingAscendingButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  customSort(sortAscendingBy, "someAttribute");
});
```

This actually does work but the problem is that it only works once, like, when I do "sortDescendingBy":

```
sortBySomethingDescendingButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  customSort(sortDescendingBy, "someAttribute");
});
```

It gives the same result as customSort(sortAscendingBy, "someAttribute")... like the data is "stuck" in ascending order just because I clicked the ascending button once, and I know that both the ascending and descending buttons each work because they work perfectly when calling the fetch() request every time... I just thought that the global array will just capture the data from the initial fetch() request.

JSON looks like this:

```
[   {
    "A": "A's value",
    "BList": [
      {
        "C": 1,
        "D": 2,
        "E": 3
      },
      {
        "C": 5,
        "D": 6,
        "E": 7
      }
    ]
      }
]
```

Sort functions look like this, these are the arguments passed as the sortOrder "callback function" parameter  :

```
export function sortDescendingBy(prop) {
  return function (a, b) {
    
    if (a[prop] > b[prop]) return -1;
  };
}
export function sortAsendingBy(prop) {
  return function (a, b) {
    
    if (a[prop] > b[prop]) return 1;
  };
}
```

Comment: So store it in a variable and use that variable.

Comment: Store fetch("theData.json").then(function (response) {return response.json()}) in a variable like let globalEmptyArray = fetch("theData.json").then(function (response) {return response.json()})? I tried that and I probably should use async await? I don't know how to store fetch() JSON responses in a variable, I'm a newbie.

Comment: It sounds like there may be an issue with your sorting function then. If the data is stored in a global variable and you can sort it once, it would appear the sorting function does something to your data/variable that prevents it from being sorted additional times. It would be helpful to know what `sortOrder()` does, and an example of what your data/object looks like

Comment: Could you add your sortAscendingBy and sortDescendingBy functions ?

Comment: @EssXTee I just did... thanks.... This all works with the customSort() function having the fetch() request within it... I'm just trying to make it work without having to have the fetch() request inside the customSort(). I just want to make one fetch() request to get the data and then work with an array once the buttons are clicked.

Comment: For clarity, yes I understood you wanted to sort without calling `fetch()` every time. However, because your sort worked only worked the first time, it showed me that the sort had to be the issue. Using `fetch()` every time just resets your data back to the original state, which is why doing that worked. This is the sort of logic that is useful in debugging your code going forward. Try to figure out *where* your code stops working and then look at the code leading up to that point. It stops on the 2nd sort, so look at what happened before (*the 1st sort*)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a problem with your sorting functions. When you want to sort an array, you should return 1 or -1.

Currently you only return one of them and the other value is undefined.

Use this code:

```js
export function sortDescendingBy(prop) {
  return function (a, b) {
    if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  };
}
export function sortAsendingBy(prop) {
  return function (a, b) {
    if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Just a note: because `a[prop] > b[prop]` returns true or false, the `if/else` part isn't needed. You can just return the statement, though you would need to reverse the greater than/less than sign accordingly.

Comment: @EssXTee Your note is good but according to the official documentations, the standard code is like what I wrote: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @EssXTee And also in TypeScript you will get error using this code: a[prop] > b[prop].

Comment: Slight mistake on my end as this wouldn't apply to the `>` or `<` comparisons, but for OP's case they are comparing numerical values. Per the MDN document you referenced, it is valid to just substract the values and return that, rather than use `if/else` statements. So returning `a[prop] - b[prop]` is valid and a little more streamlined. Also, this isn't a Typescript question so I don't see what that error would have to do with this question.

Comment: Well we're not only talking about this question (My solution solved the issue). We are talking generally. We're using typescript for strongly type check. So when we get error using < or > comparisons in TS, it means it's not the correct way to do it. But about a[prop] - b[prop] you're right. It works fine.